# How to change properties for a SAS user that is created as read-only?

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

I have created a user in SAS Management Console that can not modify his roles or accesses because his account is created as read-only and I don't know why. I have created other users in the same way and can modify them without any problem. 
What can I do to change this account so I can modify it ?
I can not even delete this account in SAS Management Console.

Comment: can you provide more details about this user?  eg username (perhaps a reserved one), permissions, the permissions of the user you are logged in as - etc?  Which version of SAS?

Comment: How about using unrestricted user? That user, by definition, can edit anything!